# Java NullPointerException even though the variable has a value

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, jbutton

I am currently working on a game written in Java.
For this I´m using JFrames, JPanels and JButtons.

To select the level you want to play, you have to select a world and then chose a level.

After launching the game, a new instance of my `WorldSelection` gets created, and after pressing a button, the chosen world gets set and a new instance of `LevelSelection` is created.

When pressing a Button there, the level gets set.

Here is my problem:

In the `Game` class, the `update` method checks the selected world and the level 60 times a second, and if both have selected values, it creates a new instance of a `Stage`/`Level`.

The moment I press a button to set the `Level`, I get a `NullPointerException`, even if the value it checks has a value.

This does not happen all of the time; half of the time it works (no Exception is thrown) and the other 50% an exception is thrown.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Game.update(Game.java:41)
at Game.run(Game.java:23)
at Game.start(Game.java:34)
at Game.<init>(Game.java:10)
at Game.main(Game.java:77)
```

Here is my Code:

Game class:

```
public class Game {
private boolean running;
private WorldSelection ws;
private boolean chosen = false;

public Game() {
    ws = new WorldSelection();
    start();
}

public void run() {             // game loop
    long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
    long timer = System.currentTimeMillis();
    final double ns = 1000000000.0 / 60.0;
    double delta = 0;
    while (running) {
        long now = System.nanoTime();
        delta += (now - lastTime) / ns;
        lastTime = now;
        while (delta >= 1) {
            update();
            delta--;
        }
        if (System.currentTimeMillis() - timer == 1000) {
            timer += 1000;
        }
    }
}

public void start() {
    running = true;
    run();
}

private void update() {

    if (!chosen) {
        if (ws.getWorld() == 1) {
            if (ws.ls.getLevel() == 1) {
                chosen = true;
                //creates new stage here
            }
            if (ws.ls.getLevel() == 2) {
                chosen = true;
                //creates new stage here
            }
            if (ws.ls.getLevel() == 3) {
                chosen = true;
                //creates new stage here
            }
        }

        else if (ws.getWorld() == 2) {
            if (ws.ls.getLevel() == 1) {
                chosen = true;
                //creates new stage here
            }
            if (ws.ls.getLevel() == 2) {
                chosen = true;
                //creates new stage here
            }
            if (ws.ls.getLevel() == 3) {
                chosen = true;
                //creates new stage here
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        //game updates here
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Game game = new Game();
}

}
```

WorldSelection class:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class WorldSelection implements ActionListener {
public JFrame frame;
private int width, height;
private int world = 0;
private JButton button1;
public LevelSelection ls;
private JPanel panel; 

public WorldSelection() {

    this.width = 900;
    this.height = 506;
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(width, height);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setTitle("Quentins Adventure");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setBackground(Color.black);

    button1 = new JButton("World 1");
    button1.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    button1.setSize(120, 44);
    button1.setLocation(80, 350);
    button1.addActionListener(this);

    panel.add(button1);

    frame.add(panel);

    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(e.getSource() == button1){
        setWorld(1);
        ls = new LevelSelection(235,268);
        frame.setVisible(false);
    }
}

public int getWorld() {
    return world;
}

public void setWorld(int world) {
    this.world = world;
}
}
```

LevelSelection class:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class LevelSelection implements ActionListener {
    public JFrame frame;
    private int width, height, buttonSize = 50;
    private int level = 0;
    private JButton button1;
    private Font font;
    private JPanel panel;


public LevelSelection(int bPosX,int bPosY) {


        this.width = 900;
        this.height = 506;
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(width, height);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setTitle("Quentins Adventure - Wold Selection");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(Color.black);

        button1 = new JButton("1");
        button1.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        button1.setFont(font);
        button1.setSize(buttonSize, buttonSize);
        button1.setLocation(bPosX, bPosY);
        button1.addActionListener(this);

        panel.add(button1);

        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }


@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(e.getSource() == button1){
        setLevel(1);
        frame.dispose();
    }
    }


public int getLevel() {
    return level;
}


public void setLevel(int level) {
    this.level = level;
}

}
```

Comment: Could you highlight the code on the line where the NPE occurs?

Comment: Where did you initialize `ls` value of `ws`?, btw, you should check if an object is null before using its methods to avoid this kind of exception.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You `setWorld` and then do `ls = new LevelSelection(235, 268);`

It means that there is moment in time when `ws.getWorld() == 1` is true, but `ws.ls` is `null`.

But it is not only problem with your code. You code is not thread safe which may lead to huge of bugs which is amount very difficult to find.

Comment: Thanks alot for your fast response, it´s working now! :)                                If you dont mind, could you explain how i could make the code "thread safe", I dont really know how fixing this would look like, since I just started working with java, and in school we arent tought how to make something thread safe:(                                                                  
 Anyway, thanks alot!

Comment: It is advanced topic. Impossible to explain in few sentences.

Answer (score 1):

In your class `WorldSelection`, reference of class `LevelSelection` is created but 
that is initialized in `ActionPerformed()`. Thus before that reference of 
`LevelSelection ls` is pointing to null.

Comment: @user2441511 Thank you so much :)